# TreeNode in TreeView with Attributes in Visual C++ - How to realize?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, treeview, treenode

I am using a TreeView's in my Visual C++ Solution to represent and alter XML-Content. I use Visual Studio 2010 for this project (.NET/Windows Forms). Some of my TreeNodes have to have Attributes. Unfortunately, TreeNodes in Visual Studio do not seem to have Attributes.

I now wanted to solve this by adding invisible Child-Nodes to TreeNodes which are supposed to have Attributes and saving the Attribute-Value in those invisible Child-Nodes. Again, TreeNodes in Visual Studio do not offer any Property for making them invisible. My Idea now was to simply derive a Custom TreeNode-Class and add a boolean Property whether the TreeNode should be hidden or not. If the property is true I "just" have to overwrite the method of the TreeView which draws the TreeNode when being added (or comes into View or whatever). Unfortunately, that's where I am stuck.  Which Function do I have to override to get this done?

BTW: Do I have to add a visibility property? Actually it should suffice to just cast the Node to the Custom-TreeNode (which is the exact same as TreeNode) and then only draw it when it is of Type TreeNode and hide when it is CustomTreeNode. Right?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: TreeView has no such option, not even with custom draw.  It is simple to do, make a node invisible by removing it from the tree.  Make sure to keep the data implementation separate from the visualization so this is never a problem.

Comment: I know, that's why I wanted to use Custom Classes for TreeNode and TreeView. For simplicity in handling and visualizing data, I wanted to have the possibility of using TreeNodes just not being displayed in the TreeView but being listed in its TreeNode-Collection.

Until now I tried to work with the Code from this page: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/treeviewex2003.aspx?msg=3979169#xx3979169xx

I wanted to use the WndProc() Hook mentioned here to prevent a TreeNode from being drawn if it is meant to be a hidden TreeNode. But I am not sure whether this is the right way to look.

Comment: Until now I only figured out this code can additionally draw something in the TreeView AFTER the Node was displayed in the TreeView. But I want to prevent the TreeNode being displayed at all.